# How to pass starred command to \fp_eval:n

Tags: macros, expl3, starred-version, l3fp

I would like to define a command that has a starred version and pass it to `\fp_eval:n` for some calculations. However, regardless of whether I use the starred or the regular version, I get the error when using the command inside `\fp_eval:n`:

```
! You can't use `\edef' after \the.
<argument> \cs_set_nopar:Npx
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand\nostar{}{1}
\fpeval{\nostar} % works fine

\NewDocumentCommand\withstar{s}{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{2}{3}}
\fpeval{\withstar} % does not work
\fpeval{\withstar*} % does not work either

\end{document}
```

Because `\fp_eval:n` is from LaTeX3, I assumed that the best way to define the command is with `\NewDocumentCommand` from `xparse`. It also attempted to use `\WithSuffix` or `\@ifstar`, but no success.

It seems the same problem occurs if I let the command have an optional argument. Mandatory arguments work fine.

Comment: The `s` argument type prevents expansion as would `[]` do as well. Both are optional argument types. Neither `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` nor `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` won't work here as well, since it ends with an optional argument, which is not allowed for that type of macros

Comment: By there way, there is `xfp` package, which does `\fpeval` for you ;-). I think, the only way to make this working, is to shift the `\fpeval` into `\withstar`, after the `\IfBoolean` test

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for your reply. I declare commands for constants and want to use them in different calculations, so putting `\fpeval` into `\withstar` is not possible for me. I am surprised that this does not work, because so far I never experienced restrictions on where commands with optional arguments or stars can be used. Does this mean there is no chance to do what I would like, even when using a different way than `\NewDocumentCommand` to declare my command? Or somehow forcing expansion of the arguments? If there is no way, maybe this should be an answer?

Comment: I know of now way, but this does not mean that there's none! Perhaps you have to use another approach instead of using `*` - commands

Comment: You can make a command with a *-variant expandable only if it also has a trailing mandatory argument: `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\withstar}{sm}{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{2}{3}}` and call it as `\fpeval{\withstar{}}` or `\fpeval{\withstar*{}}`. Just the * cannot work, because in this case LaTeX has to perform assignments in order to peek at the next token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commands with a *-variant cannot, in general, work in an expansion context, which is required by `\fp_eval:n`.

The problem is that the macro has to look forward in order to see if a * follows and the only safe way is to do a peek with `\futurelet` which then makes the construction not fully expandable. This affects `\@ifstar`, `\WithSuffix` and `\NewDocumentCommand`.

There is a workaround with `xparse`, but it requires the macro have a trailing mandatory argument. After

```
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\myvar}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{2}{3}%
}
```

you can call

```
\fpeval{\myvar{}}
\fpeval{\myvar*{}}
```

Complete example; note that `xfp` takes care of defining `\fpeval`.

```
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse,xfp}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\nostar{m}{1}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\withstar{sm}{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{2}{3}}

\begin{document}

\fpeval{\nostar{}} % works fine

\fpeval{\withstar{}} % works fine

\fpeval{\withstar*{}} % works fine

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also defined `\star` with a mandatory argument for uniformity. Think to it as C.

Comment: It seems etextools manages to do it, somehow (with `\FE@ifstar`)? (Sadly, the package seems to be incompatible with (e.g.) BibLaTeX…)

Comment: @MagnusLieHetland `etextools` is not only incompatible with `biblatex`.